# Difference between the two regular expression

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions

I came across a question to create a regular expression to check whether there are even number of b's in a string of language {a,b}. The expression I came up with is (a+ba*b)*. However I found the solution online to be a*(ba*ba*). Is there any difference? If any where?

Also I know that (a+b)* is equivalent to (a*b*)*. So my solution comes out to be (a*(ba*b))*. So why that extra a*?

Comment: I think you'll need to edit the question, as I can't tell what you are asking.  1. `(a+b)*` is not equivalent to `(a*b*)`.  Please double-check all your statements.  Proof-read the formatted output, and consider using Markdown to typeset your notation more clearly.  2. What have you tried?  Have you tried to look for a string that is accepted by  your expression but not by the other one, or vice versa?   Have you taken a look at closure properties, to see how to compute the set difference between two regexps?    (continued)

Comment: 3. Please use typesetting to reduce ambiguity.  Does `(a+ba*b)*` mean `(a+(ba*b))*` or `((a+b)a*b)*`?  4. I can't tell what "check whether for even number of b's in a language of {a,b}" means.  Can you please edit to rewrite that?  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression **(a+ba*b)*** won't match the string *a* which contains zero *b*'s, an even number.  It also won't match the strings *bb* or *bbbb*, because the expression requires one or more *a*'s before any occurring *b*'s and requires at least one *a* between any two pairs of *b*'s.

The regular expression **a*(ba*ba*)*** is the correct solution.  It allows any number of leading *a*'s and then demands that there if there are *b*'s present there be at least two *b*'s among the remaining *a*'s.  Thereafter *b*'s are matched in groups of two among the *a*'s and matching will fail if a *b* occurs outside such a pair.

The regular expression **a*(ba*b)*** is wrong because it won't match strings with *a*'s between pairs of *b*'s, such as the string *bbaabb*.

Comment: But a* means that there can be even 0 a's. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Basic_concepts

Comment: @AdwaitKumar the issue is not in 0 a's between bb, but your regular expression a*(ba*b)*not permit aa between 2 bb's . expand it a bit you can get a*(ba*b)(ba*b)..., clearly it forces no a's between 2nd and 3rd b's, etc.

Comment: In fact $(a+ba^*b)^* $ does correctly represent an even number of $b$'s. The expression has a repeated alternative between a single $a$ and a sequence of two $b$'s with an arbitrary numbers of $a$'s in between. The star allows zero iterations. Also $a^*(ba^*b)^* $ is indeed wrong, but it will match $a$'s between $b$'s. The reason it is wrong is that we cannot end with the letter $a$ unless we only have $a$'s.